# Why wasn't this titan involved in any military operation until at least the 3rd Season of the anime?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Warning: Major spoilers below.

In the operation to retake the Founding Titan, the Female Titan, the Jaw Titan, the Armored Titan and the Colossus Titan were sent for it.

In the last episodes of the Season 3 of the anime, we see the Armored Titan, the Colossus Titan, the Beast Titan and the Cart Titan fighting Erwin, Eren, Levi, Mikasa, etc.

Why was the

> War Hammer Titan

not involved in any military operation until at least the 3rd Season of the anime, if he also is in the power of the people of Marley?

Comment: They totally did not. This is a spoiler for anime-only people.

Comment: I edited the question after having watched the latest episode (the titan was not shown by the way). I doubt that they'd even show the titan until during the middle of the next season, assuming there is one. I think they'd just probably drop a mention or two during the last episodes, for the watcher's excitement, especially those who only watch the anime.

Comment: @JustPlain Were you spoiled? I apologize. I did not notice. I was quite surprised too that this titan was said to have been in the 3rd season, when it is still not even mentioned.

Comment: Well, at least it's not a major spoiler so not big of a problem there. Thanks for the edit. @W. Are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: Major spoilers below.

It was explained in **Chapter 95**.

> Zeke told them that as both honorary Marleyans and aristocrats, *the Tybur family followed a policy of non-interference in both politics and war*.

**Why were they involved in the military operations now, of all times?**

Zeke further explained that

> given the recent fears of the future of Eldia and Marley, they finally agreed to take action. So, the current situation (failure of Marley to recover the Coordinate and lose the Colossal) caused the Tybur family to agree to take action after years of not doing so. They now see Eldia as a threat not just to Marley but also to the world.

In later chapters,

> they will use the Tybur family to rally the nations and show to them that they should unite against the growing threat (Eldia). They somewhat succeeded, at the cost of the Warhammer Titan falling into Eldia's hands.